# how to ionic in convert html to image

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic4

I will try in domtoimage package module use but it's not working. Please suggest to me how it works.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';     
constructor() {


    setTimeout(() => {
      var node = document.getElementById('htmltoimage');

  domtoimage.toPng(node,{ quality: 0.95 })
    .then(function (dataUrl) {
        
      var img = new Image();
      img.src = dataUrl;
      document.body.appendChild(img);
        console.log(dataUrl);
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.download = 'my-image-name.jpeg';
        link.href = dataUrl;
        link.click();
        
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
    });
    }, 1000 * 3);
    
  }
```

the output is data;